# Error while building wheel for JPype1 in Python 3.12

Tags: python-3.x, jpype

I am trying to install JPype1 (version 1.4.1) in python 3.12 but I get the following error

```
jp_primitivetype.cpp
      native\common\jp_primitivetype.cpp(50): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jpype1
Failed to build jpype1
ERROR: Could not build wheels for jpype1, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I entered the command "pip install jpype".
I expected jpype to be installed but got this error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen pages suggesting that you drop to a lower version of pip and/or python

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506267/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-jpype1-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).